# Show SFTP connection status inside a tool that is not connected to Internet

Tags: c#, sftp, tcp

I'm building a tool in c# which doesn't have access to internet. IT team has access to a SFTP server, downloads a file from that server and uploads it to an internal network which my tool can access. I want to show the status(Up or down) of SFTP server in the tool.  How can I show the status in the tool?

Comment: You can TCP connect to the SFTP server (on SFTP port). If you get connected - the status is Green. If Connect timeout or Exception - Its Red

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps to achieve the task:

1. First write Batch to Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to
   SFTP server.
2. Also write a batch which gives details about SFTP network status
3. Now Use Internal Network to Get status of SFTP network.